# how to target IE 6 AND IE7 in css

Tags: html, css

Hi all : How can i fix the problem of css in ie 7 and ie6 : my divs change possition in those two : www.justcode/housetostay: I will be very glad if i get any help

Comment: [CSS star hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Star_hack).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use conditionals to do this.

In your  add this code.

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    // Add your IE only stylesheet here
<![endif]-->
```

This means that if the browser is Less Than IE8 load the stylesheet in the comments.

You can be more specific if you need to.

`<!--[if IE ]>` - Targets all IE versions from 5.5 up to 9

`<!--[if gt IE6 ]>` - Targets all IE versions Greater Than IE6

`<!--[if IE7 ]>` - Targets only IE7

Comment: `<!--[if IE]>` targets all IE versions from 5.5 up to 9. None before that, none after that.

Comment: I'm surprised people still recommend/use this technique and create up to 4 stylesheets when you can use 1 stylesheet and group your CSS more efficiently... Whatever floats your boat I guess!

Comment: In a perfect world there shouldn't be much need to do either but I like having all IE fixes in one place.

Answer (score 1):

Without using hacks I would suggest using this technique

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="ie6"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html><!--<![endif]-->
```

Then you can add css:

```
.ie6 .my-div {

}
.ie7 .my-div {

}
```

Using separate stylesheets for each version of IE is pretty outdated/poor IMO when you can target all versions in your regular single stylesheet

you can read more here: http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/